# SQL Server Agent job fails to backup to remote folder

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backup

I have created a SQL Server Agent job (in SQL 2008 R2) to back up some databases on a server. This task runs fine when the backup folder is set to a folder on that machine, but when I try to set it to a remote folder location, it does not work. I get the rather unhelpful error `Execution of job 'xxx' failed. See the history log for details.` I've looked at the windows event log and I see the message `Package "DailyBackup" failed.

Is there a way to get more detailed logging? Also, is what I am trying to do even possible (i.e. write backups to a folder on another server). Note I can happily access the folder on the other server and create files etc, so I assume this is not an issue with access rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL server is referring to the SQL Server Log, not the Windows Event log.

Your SQL Agent process has no permissions to write to the remote location; you will have to grant access to the user running the SQL Agent process.